# How to release Soundpool in android

Tags: android, soundpool

While I am scanning racks using barcode, I implemented a singleton class of soundpool, while continue scans, automatically app closed. The error is "Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel".

```
 public void successfulAlert() {
    Logger.d("", "SuccessAlert Start" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    final int audioID = mSPool.load(Application.getInstance(), R.raw.scan, 1);
    mSPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            Logger.d("", "SuccessAlert Completed " + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            float volume = (float) mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mSPool.play(audioID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
          ///  cleanupSound();
        }
    });
    Logger.d(TAG, "Possitive Scan Beep ");
}
```

This code for success alert, I try to cleanup the soundpool release, sound not heared. Can anyone suggest me, how to release soundpool after playing a sound.

```
 public void cleanupSound() {
    if (mSPool != null) {
        mSPool.release();
       // mSPool=null;
       // mAudioManager.unloadSoundEffects();
       // mInstance=null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Question is two fold:
1) Why is my sound not playing?
2) How do I correctly release a SoundPool?

For 1 - SoundPool play is asynchronous. You are doing: "play then release" but you need to do "play then wait-until-play-has-completed then release".

For 2 - Due to 1, you ought not to release a SoundPool until play has completed. Unfortunately, there is *no way* to ask the SoundPool to callback when it has finished playing. I've seen two solutions to this:

- If you  know how long it will take to play the sample (X ms), schedule your `release`, for X ms in the future, perhaps using `postDelayed` from `Handler`.
- Decide that the truly important concern is that the SoundPool is released when your application is finished. So, monitor all exit points from your application, and ensure that, at each, the SoundPool is released. If someone closes the application while you are playing sound, you might abruptly cut that effect, but this is probably the correct behaviour as your application is exiting!

Note: To be a truly well behaved Android citizen, your application should only play sound if it has first acquired, and continues to hold, the Audio Focus. More info on that here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html